# Blurry image after scale in Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a big image as background-image, and I reduce the size on scroll, and in the same time I modify the background-position too.

Unfortunately I found problems in Chrome and Safari. In these browsers as soon as I start to scroll the image become blurry.

I tried many solutions for that problem, but no luck. Do you have idea what's wrong, or an other method what can help to achieve the same effect?

JS

```
function promo_scroll() {
    var current_scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var scale = 5;
    var window_height = jQuery(window).height();
    var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
    var correction = jQuery('#header-wrapper').height()-500;

    if(scale*((1-(current_scroll/window_height))) > 1 && (window_width/window_height >= 198/119)) {
        jQuery('#custom-header').removeAttr('data-top');

        jQuery('.container').css({
            'position'  : 'fixed',  
            'display' : 'block',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'transform' : 'scale(' + scale*((1-(current_scroll/window_height))) + ')',
        });

        jQuery('.container:not(.content)').css('background-position', '0 ' + correction + 'px');


    } else if(window_width/window_height >= 198/119) {
        if (typeof jQuery('#custom-header').attr('data-top') == 'undefined'){
            jQuery('#custom-header').attr('data-top',jQuery('#custom-header').offset().top);
            jQuery('#content-wrapper').css('padding-top',jQuery('#custom-header').offset().top);
        }
        jQuery('.container').css({
            top : jQuery('#custom-header').attr('data-top')-current_scroll,
            'transform' : 'scale(1)',
        });
    }
    else{
        jQuery('#custom-header').removeAttr('data-top');
        jQuery('#content-wrapper').css('padding-top',0);

        jQuery('.container').css({
            'background-position': 'center top',
            'position'  : 'absolute',   
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'transform' : 'scale(1)',
        });
        jQuery('.container.content').css({
            'position' : 'absolute'
        });
    }
}

jQuery(document).on('click','#custom-header', function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({'scrollTop': jQuery('.l-grid-row').offset().top - jQuery('#main-header').outerHeight()},2500);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    promo_scroll();
});

jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){
    jQuery('.container.content')[0].style.setProperty('background-position', jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 'px 50%', 'important');
    promo_scroll();
});

jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
    jQuery('#custom-header').removeAttr('data-top');
    promo_scroll();
});
```

CSS

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.container {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
    will-change: transform;
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: blur(0px); 
-moz-filter: blur(0px); 
-ms-filter: blur(0px);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
}

.container.content{
    z-index: 5;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/f68DPZG.jpg');
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#header-wrapper {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #header-wrapper {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 198/119) {
    .container {
        -webkit-transform: scale(5);
        -moz-transform: scale(5);
        transform: scale(5);
        background-size: 100% auto !important;
        background-position: center center !important;
    }
}

.spacing {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header-wrapper" data-full-height-header="true">
    <div id="custom-header" class="container"></div>
    <div class="container content"></div>
</div>
<div class="spacing">
</div>
```

The effect is visible only with a specific aspect ratio, so please check the link in full screen: https://jsfiddle.net/4eod1ng5/3/embedded/#Result

[image: Before scroll]

[image: After scroll]

**Update:** After several testing it looks like the problem occurs only in OSX (Safari and Chrome)
**Update 2:** After I updated my chrome to 51 in linux the problem appeared.

Comment: There is some scaling issue.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately your fiddle does not work well for me, i can see some kind of weirdness, but i cannot run the fiddle when i edit it. however, running the code in my head:

you are using scale in combination with a blur effect. when you use scale 5, it will not re-initialize the effect, but only scale up the object. i would try starting with a big size (width + height = 500%) and rather scaling it down (scale < 1) than up.

you can also try transforming the container instead of the object with the background image. that helped for me occasionaly when dealing with problems like this.

Comment: Yes, you can run the fiddle in full screen because it works with specific aspect ratio. I will try that method, thanks.

Comment: did you get around to trying it?

Answer (score -1):

I tried the jsFidle. the problem I see here is because the images are low resolution, try to use higher resolutions images

Comment: If the image is low resolution you should see the blurry image on the initial load too, not only after scroll. The image size is: 6144px × 822px. If you tried it in chrome you can see the difference between the initial load and after scroll.

Comment: 822px is low its true you have 6144px as width but the image height is low 
I tested it on chrome on windows on a 4k screen and I saw the issue scrolled up all the way. 
I can tell you if you use image with height more than say 2000px you will not see the problem

Comment: Please check the attached images. Of course the first not sharp as a HD photo, but sharper than the second. It appears in osx chrome and safari, so if you have Linux/Windows you won't see that.

Comment: After updating my chrome to 51 in linux the problem appeared. So it's not an osx specific bug.

Comment: can you please try this iamge
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1048F698C070ED2F!24852&authkey=!AFH1xF1179BUoKU&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: I tried it, the result is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/4eod1ng5/8/embedded/#Result